# Regex inverse matching on specific string?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I would like to match the following

- com.my.company.**moduleA**.MyClassName
- com.my.company.**moduleB**.MyClassName
- com.my.company.**anythingElse**.MyClassName

but ***not*** the following

- com.my.company.**core**.MyClassName

My current simple regex pattern is :

```
Pattern PATTERN_MODULE_NAME = Pattern.compile("com\\.my\\.company\\.(.*?)\\..*")

Matcher matcher = PATTERN_MODULE_NAME.matcher(className);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // will return the string inside the parentheses (.*?)
    return matcher.group(1);
}
```

So, basically, how can i match everything else, but not a specific string, which is the string **core** in my case.

Please share your ideas on how to achieve that in Java ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^com\\.my\\.company\\.(?!core).+?\\.MyClassName$
```

Comment: +1, but it looks like you've got an extra dot right before that last pair of backslashes.

Comment: codaddict: Thanks ! That's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a regex is not the clearest way to write this.

```
if (className.startsWith("com.my.company.") 
    && !className.startsWith("com.my.company.core.")) {

}
```

This is fair clear what it does, and you might find it is faster. ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's simple and clean. :-)

Comment: Regex are cool but can become a cryptic string of symbols which can make it hard for someone reading it later to determine exactly what it does or how to change it.