# java regex to accept any word other than none

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match any string other than none.
 I tried using 
    regular exp ="^[^none]$",
But it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean "other than 'none'"?  If so why not match 'none' and negate the result?

Comment: Do you only want to fail if your string is "none"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression `(?!^none$).*`.  See this question for details: [Regex inverse matching on specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263923/regex-inverse-matching-on-specific-string)

The reason `"^[^none]$"` doesn't work is that you are actually matching all strings except the strings "n", "o", or "e".

Of course, it would be easier to just use `String.equals` like so: `!"none".equals(testString)`.

Comment: The regular expression  "^(?!none).+$" is not accepting the String nonetheless. The regular expression should not accept none. It should accept all other words. How can I modify the expression?

Comment: @user679526 I got it now.  `^(?!none).+$` matches any word that doesn't start with "none".  I edited my answer with the regex `(?!^none$).*` which should match every string except "none".

Answer (score 1):

If you are matching a `String` against a specific word in Java you should use `equals()`. In this case you want to invert the match so your logic becomes:

```
if(!theString.equals("none")) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

Much less resource hungry, and much more intuitive.

If you need to match a String which contains the word "none", you are probably looking for something like:

```
if(theString.matches("\\bnone\\b")) {
  /* matches theString if the substring "none" is enclosed between 
   * “word boundaries”, so it will not match for example: "nonetheless"
   */
}
```

Or if you can be fairly certain that “word boundaries” mean a specific delimiter you can still evade regular expressions by using the `indexOf()` method:

```
int i = theString.indexOf("none");
if(i > -1) {
    if(i > 0) {
       // check theString.charAt(i - 1) to see if it is a word boundary 
       // e.g.: whitespace
    }
    // the 4 is because of the fact that "none" is 4 characters long.
    if((theString.length() - i - 4) > 0) {
       // check theString.charAt(i + 4) to see if it is a word boundary 
       // e.g.: whitespace
    }
}
else {
    // not found.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the regex to match all words except "word":

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?!word\\b)\\w+\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```

You must use word boundaries so that "word" is not contained in other words.

**Explanation:**

```
"
\b          # Assert position at a word boundary
(?!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   Lorem       # Match the characters “Lorem” literally
   \b          # Assert position at a word boundary
)
\w          # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b          # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you are looking for:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!none$).*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("your string");
System.out.println(s + ": " + (m.matches() ? "Match" : "NO Match"));
```

Having that said, if you are not forced to use a regex that matches everything but "none", the more simple, fast, clear, and easy to write and understand is this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^none$");
```

Then, you just exclude the matches.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("your string");
System.out.println(s + ": " + (m.matches() ? "NO Match" : "Match"));
```