# Is there a way to exclude certain files in a fileset using containsregexp?

Tags: regex, ant

Is there a way in ant to exclude certain files from a fileset using a regular expression?

containsregexp can be used to include files, but how do I exclude files matching a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`<not>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#notselect) selector container.  The Ant docs example

```
<fileset dir="." includes="*.txt">
    <containsregexp expression="[4-6]\.[0-9]"/>
</fileset>
```

could be negated thus:

```
<fileset dir="." includes="*.txt">
    <not>
        <containsregexp expression="[4-6]\.[0-9]"/>
    </not>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `!` to prefix a regex pattern to invert the matching.

Here are some related discussion on inverted regex matching:

- [How to "inverse match" with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex)
- [Invert match with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp)
- [Regex inverse matching on specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263923/regex-inverse-matching-on-specific-string)
- [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)